# How to configure in Startup a generic static class?

Tags: asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection, .net-5, static-classes

To configure a static class with DI in .NET Core I can do this:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
}
```

Then in Startup:

```
MyStaticClass.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
```

How to register a GENERIC static class on Startup?

```
public static class MyGenericStaticClass<T>
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
}
```

Then on Startup what?

I tried this but obviously it is missing the generic type and throwing an error:

```
MyGenericStaticClass.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>);
```

and I am not sure where to declare the type?

Comment: I would suggest you refer to the fix mentioned at [Register Generic Classes in ASP.NET Core DI](https://medium.com/null-exception/register-generic-classes-in-asp-net-core-di-1ef0f1fc3e5). See Whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare type like below.

```
MyGenericStaticClass<declare type here>.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>);
```